# How to optimize filtering of large observable collection in wpf

Tags: wpf, filtering, observablecollection

I have for loop of datatable Employees  with count 12k and inside that loop i want to filter a collection based on Employeeid. The collection has 22k records . I have used linq query to filter this collection. Due to this filtering loop has performance issue. How can i optimize filtering of large collection.

Comment: whaty about the CollectionView here is the article that can help with that - http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html.

Answer (score 0):

Optimize it? Cut down on the ridiculous amount of elements BEFORE turning that over to WPF.

You should not load that stuff into memory to start with and let the database do the filtering.